# Most common naming for graph edges ("to $\to$ from" vs "in $\to$ out" vs "source $\to$ target", etc)

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Within the world of graph theory when discussing and documenting a graph structure, which is the most common terminology used to describe the edge relationship between the nodes?

So far, we have the following options under discussion:

$$\begin{align}
\text{to} &\to \text{from} \\
\text{in} &\to \text{out} \\
\text{source} &\to \text{target}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `graphing-functions`?

Comment: These don't seem like grammatically the same kinds of words, so I don't see how they could be terminology for the same thing. Can you give examples of the way you're planning on using these in a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

To me (with little formal graph theory education) those three things signify slightly different things. This is what my gut says:

- To-From: For a pair of vertices, there can be an edge going from one and to the other
- In-Out: For a given vertex, some edges go in, some edges go out
- Source-Target: For a given edge, one vertex is the source, and one vertex is the target